# Sound through HDMI does not work under pipeware on Fedora 35

Tags: audio, fedora

I recently installed Fedora 35. I used an HDMI cable to use a TV as a second screen. I am able to use the video, but the audio does not work on the screen when using this computer.

Fedora 35 currently uses pipeware + wireplumber by default, as described at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/WirePlumber

I already tried to switch to pipewire-media-session as described above, but it did not work.

The sound through HDMI works: I can play a testing sound using `speaker-test`:

```sh
$ speaker-test -c2 -f440 -tsine -Dhdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
```

`gnome-settings` shows me "HDMI/DisplayPort - Internal audio" as an option to use, but there is no sound.

However, the sound does not work using pipeware on Gnome. Follows some more information:

```sh
$aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pipewire
    PipeWire Sound Server
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3234 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3234 Analog
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3234 Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3234 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3234 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3234 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3234 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC3234 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

probably, you use a video card shared with your cpu. Try adding support like this.

1. Open terminal and type

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
   ```
2. Add this at the end of the file:

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel model=auto
   ```
3. Active IOMMU in boot:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
4. Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on,igfx_off"
   ```
5. Save the file and update grup.

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
6. Reboot

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Gabriele Lagana. It seems something to try. Unfortunately, I do not have this TV available anymore. It works in the new TV. But if I manage to get a similar TV as before to test it I will post an update here.